# How can i just kill a process when c# based program incurs a runtime error with messagebox

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I can detect when some process have exited normally but when process occurs a runtime error with messagebox showing info about the error, I can't detect the program is having problem.

Is there some build option that can just finalize the program without runtime error box
or if there's no way, how can I detect the program is having a runtime error from another watchdog program?

Comment: I assume you are looking for Try-Catch, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx

Comment: I'm very confused about what you're asking. You want to build the application with it ignoring any errors? Or show a message box of what the error is?

Comment: @EBrown see improved question writeup.

Comment: @EyeSeeSharp See improved question writeup.

Comment: There are no simple solutions to a problem like this, but one.  You'd need a UI Automation library to detect the message box.  A timeout on the process completion is a crude way.  Only real fix is a telephone, ask for a extra command line argument you can pass to suppress the message boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way is to have the application listen for a application being watched for failures listen and respond back to UDP packets originating from the watchdog application. Failure to echo back a UDP packet on time might be an indication that the application is hanging and the watchdog can kill it and launch it again. This called a heart beat.

That said, this is a quick and dirty solution. You would be better off avoiding message boxes appearing in what seems to be a long running application.  You should handle all exceptions and exit gracefully instead of having to kill that application.

Comment: i think udp ping is not helpful. because when runtime error occured, the other thread do normally.

Comment: the error was about clr level. should i have to surround root code of program with try catch

Comment: Use a thread to receive the udp packet but invoque the method to respond via the UI thread.

Comment: Yes, you are better off handling the exception instead of using workarounds.

Comment: Thanks about your comment!